# Android onTouch(View,MotionEvent) not called but onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) is called?

Tags: android

Does anyone know why my logs indicate that onTouch(View, MotionEvent) does not get called. I can see that onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) is being called. Both are overridden in Activity which implements View.OnTouchEvent.

Comment: Why are you overridden onTouch() and onTouchEvent() at the Activity? Shouldn't it be using setOnTouchListener() in your Activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, Activity does not define `onTouch(..)`, but it does define `onTouchEvent(..)`. So you are overriding the latter, but merely defining the former.

Also, the `onTouchEvent(..)` is a last resort touch handler - it gets called only if views do not handle it:

```
onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
Called when a touch screen event was not handled by any of the views under it.
```

Comment: ok.  I am trying to do a swipe to change the activity.  So I think the only way to use what I have is   View view = findViewById(R.id.startButtonLayout);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);

Answer (score 4):

`onTouch()` is called when a `View` is touched,but `onTouchEvent()` is called when the `Activity` (the screen) is touched.

When the return value of `onTouch()` is true, the touch event will be comsumed by the `onTouch()`, otherwise, the event will be delivered to the `onTouchEvent()`.

Hope it's useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

onTouch can be used in android.some thing like this use in ur activity.no need to override

```
      ed.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hai",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This may not work because returning false tells NOT to consume the event!